# RISCV on zynq ultrascale+ zcu102

Tags: fpga, riscv

I want to load riscv on zcu102 xilinx board. I looked at various sites, they have codes for other specific boards and I am not quite sure how to port it.
Since I am a beginner, can you provide some starting point for it ?

I tried lowrisc implementation but i am not able to port it to zcu102.

---

Sorry for ambiguity. I wanted to run riscv soc platform such as lowrisc on fpga. But the code given in their github is optimized for nexy4 ddr board. And I am getting issues for converting it to zcu102. So, I was asking if there is some steps I can follow ? Like list of interfaces need to be changed ?

Comment: Just so there is no misunderstanding: You want to take RISC-V HDL (Verilog or VHDL) code and get it working on a ZCU102 Xilinx board.

Comment: Yes. I want to run any SOC platform such as rocketchip or lowrisc

Comment: I have updated your question with the vital information you gave in a comment. As it stands the question is too broad. Try to get ask *specific* questions like *"How do I connect interface A of code B to interface C of the board."* This is not a trivial task unless you have decent experience in working with HDL languages.

Answer (score 0):

Risc-V is not a processor.

Risc-V is an Instructions Set ([ISA](https://riscv.org/risc-v-cores/)) implemented by some processors.
Then if you want to "load" a Risc-V processor you have to choose one, then synthetize it with your FPGA tools ([Vivado](https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado.html) for Xilinx).

[Here a list of Risc-V cores](https://riscv.org/risc-v-cores/) on Risc-v fondation website.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I wanted to run riscv soc platform such as lowrisc on fpga. But the code given in their github is optimized for nexy4 ddr board. And I am getting issues for converting it to zcu102. So, I was asking if there is some steps I can follow  ? Like list of interfaces need to be changed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Instant Soc](http://www.fpga-cores.com/instant-soc/) from FPGA Cores.
The compiler builds a soc including this [RISC-V](http://www.fpga-cores.com/instant-soc/risc-v/) processor and UARTs, I2Cs etc directly from C++. All peripherals are defined as C++ objects. Very easy to use.
I have mostly used it with Artix to interface the AXIS streams on the [Ethernet cores](http://www.fpga-cores.com/).